# How can I use Overwatch with no internet connection?

Tags: overwatch

This question has probably been asked before: how can I play Overwatch without WiFi? When I *do* have WiFi, I can play against AI, but that's *kinda* pointless if I can just play online; with friends. So, is there a hack or game-code change I can use to play with AI with no  WiFi?

Comment: We're not going to help you hack the game.

Comment: Overwatch is an online game. Online games require internet. Period. There are no hacks, workarounds, or exploits that will allow you to download the server code and play locally without internet. This is true for nearly every single online-only game in existence.

Answer (score 10):

When playing against AI, you're still playing on a Blizzard server. There is no way to play against AI locally.

Comment: There's no way to download the AI code locally?

Comment: @pagie_ No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

When you launch overwatch, there's a brief period before you hit the main menu when you're connecting to a server. You literally cannot get to the main menu without connecting to a server.

You're also mentioning hacking or game-code changes in relation to a blizzard game, which they have mentioned ammounts to cheating in any capacity